# How to debug seg fault in docker container?

Tags: javascript, docker, segmentation-fault

I'm running ESLint - a linter for javascript files - in a container:
https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-eslint

The program runs the ESLint cli `analyze` command and provides a directory of code to analyze mounted as a volume in the container.

The program captures the ESLint results and reformats them, then re-outputs to STDOUT.

Normally this works fine, but in the face of very large number of issues in single files - e.g. minified files - the process **segfaults**. The only error provided:

`Segmentation fault`

Since running ESLint natively by itself on the same code base does not, I attribute the cause to something related to the containerization.

I've experimented with significantly upping the memory and --ulimit on container to no avail. I've also done some googling but not found a specific case that sounds similar.

Any ideas for a good next steps on debugging this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same error in a similar situation : have you improved since? Do you reckon the problem was memory-related? Did you end-up debugging with gdb as suggesed? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can permit core files by running `ulimit -c unlimited` in a script that launches your app. Then you can process the core file with a debugger (e.g. gdb) to find the cause of the segfault. To get the core file out of a stopped container, there's `docker cp $container_id:/path/to/core /host/destination/core`.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm running a node process, I started experimenting with https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler.

Ultimately, someone on our team discovered that switching from alpine to a different node base image improved the tool's ability to handle lots of STDOUT. https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-eslint/pull/119/files